# electrochemistry experiment

Tags: experimental-chemistry, electrochemistry, home-experiment

something strange.
i made an electrochemistry experiment in which i have measured the potential of cell:
Ag, AgCl | (1M)KCl ║ [Fe(CN)6] 3-, [Fe(CN)6] 4-  | Pt

with different concentrations of Fe+2/Fe+3 .
from the results i have found the faraday constant:
96181 Coulon /mol
very close to the published value (99.7% accuracy).

the intercept of the graph of E (v) against ln(Fe+2/Fe+3)   is:

```
intercept:    0.198985714  V
```

(the intercept is also the standard potential for the cell)

yet, when i tried to find the standard potential of

```
Fe3+ +e- -> Fe2+
```

i got the result of +0.423 V which is almost half of the published value (+0.77 V)

```
E_cathode =E^° + E_anode  

E_cathode=0.198985+0.224= +0.423 V
```

**how can it be that the faraday constant is almost accurate and in the same time the result of the standard potential is far from the real one.?** i'm sure i don't have any calculation mistakes, if it's necessary i can describe the method of work here.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you are measuring is not the potential $Fe^{2+}/Fe^{3+}$. It is the potentiel of the couple $[Fe(CN)_6]^{4-}/[Fe(CN)_6]^{3-}$ which is equal to +0.36 V in the table.

Comment: which table are you using?

Comment: This is more suited as a comment Maurice

Comment: My table is "Chemistry Data Book" , by J G Stark and H G Wallace, p. 70, edited by John Murray, 50 Albermale St, London W1X 4BD, 1994, ISBN 0-7195-3951-X. It has been reprinted every two years since.

Comment: thanks! but still the faraday constant is more accurate by 14% than the standard potential, even though i used the standard potential for obtaining it.